# Extracting coordinates (of a node), and the one-node-path-trick

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

If one has nodes (vector0) and (vector1), one method to get the first and second coordinate of

```
       ($(vector1)-(vector0)$)
```

is to write

```
      \path ($(vector1)-(vector0)$);
      \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};
```

This method appears, for example, in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130731/how-to-extract-coordinates-in-the-current-scope-before-the-coordinate-transform)

where one finds

> \path (A); \pgfgetlastxy{\xA}{\yA}; % Extract the coordinates of A

Or, more precisely, the method I descibed above consists of replacing "A" with $(vector0)-(vector1)$.

Another thread in which this method appears is 
[this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116285/extracting-x-y-coordinates-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz-while-using-yscale-and)

where one finds

> \path (z) node[below] {$z$};
>     \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};

**Question.**

Briefly: how *should* one do this?

In more detail:

- what noteworthy methods are there to, if one at some point of a TikZ program has nodes (vector0) and (vector1), get the first and second coordinate of ($(vector1)-(vector0)$) ?
- Which of these methods should one use and when? In particular, should one avoid this one-node-path-trick?
- In particular, how to do this more quickly, in more or less one line, e.g.  by writing something like

  ```
   \node (tempnode) at ($(vector1)-(vector0)$)[]{};
   \pgfgetlastxy {      code involving (tempnode)   } { another code involving (tempnode) };
  ```

?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> - what noteworthy methods are there to, if one at some point of a TikZ program has nodes (vector0) and (vector1), get the first and second coordinate of ($(vector1)-(vector0)$) ?

There is the `let` operation.

[image]

> - Which of these methods should one use and when? In particular, should one avoid this one-node-path-trick?

You should only use the `let` operation because it's the only high-level method.

> - In particular, how to do this quicker, in more or less one line, e.g. by writing something like

The `let` operation is part of the path and therefore one line, see also example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,fill,circle,label={above:vector 0}] (vector0) at (1,2) {};
  \node[draw,fill,circle,label={above:vector 1}] (vector1) at (3,1) {};
  \draw let \p1=($(vector1)-(vector0)$) in
    (vector0) -- +(\x1,0) -- +(\x1,\y1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]